# How to access Beausoleil Island for a day trip, without the DayTripper?

Tags: ontario

The problem with the DayTripper is [its too early scheduled return trip (4 hours after the departure time)](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/on/georg/visit/daytripper) and allows too little time for me; I hope to spend the whole day until daylight's end.

Is there any reliable, economical alternative water transportation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parks Canada](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/on/georg/visit/directions) offers a variety of options below. Not sure about the price, so it could add up - but it's worth a call.

> Access to the park is by boat only. Due to the limited capacity of our
>   DayTripper shuttle boat service, Georgian Bay Islands National Park is
>   not able to transport tent campers to Beausoleil Island. The following
>   private businesses offer water taxi services for campers. Advanced
>   bookings recommended. Please contact them for details:
>
> CNC Marina: 705-794-5059 or 705-756-3231
>
> Georgian Bay Water Services: 705-627-3062
>
> Honey Harbour Boat Club: 705-756-2411
>
> Honey Harbour Small Motors 705-756-2151